# Using grep to find the correspondent error line item

Tags: awk, grep

I have the log file like this. I want to use grep command to find the reference to the error message which I want to get: "/home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml". Would that be possible using grep command?

The first line (/home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml) is random from the log file, what I want to get is the first line actually!

```
> /home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml
> [C]:https://geocoder.com/geocode.json?t=United States
> [C]:https://geocoder.com/geocode.json?t=United States
> [C]:https://geocoder.com/geocode.json?t=United States
> [C]:https://geocoder.com/geocode.json?t=United States { Error: connect
> ETIMEDOUT 54.210.239.167:443
>     at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'connect',  
> address: '54.210.239.167',   port: 443 }
```

Comment: Yes, I think it would be.

Comment: do you want to open the file/ search a parse in that file?

Comment: `grep` is for doing `g/re/p` (there is a big hint in the command name!) which is NOT what you're now asking about so you should not even consider using grep for this, just use awk instead. So are you just looking for the word "error" to `find the reference to the error message` or something else? If so how do you identify which preceding line contains the file name - some number of lines before it, or it matches some specific regexp or something else? [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Comment: @user3736228 Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

```
grep -B 10 ETIMEDOUT logfile.log | grep xml
```

I understand your ask like this. If a file is errored out, then the said filename has to be found. For the same, the below should work.

```
-B brings the said number of lines above the matched pattern/string, it's 10 here
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `>` characters are not part of the file. Then what about:

```
$ grep "^/" file
/home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml
```

If it's part of the file, then for example:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=^> )/.*" file
/home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes the ">" is not part of the log file. I forgot to say something, actually I wanted to get this line: /home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml. So I know which XML file I need to re-process.

Comment: @user3736228 The provided grep command does print that line (`/home/ubuntu/CT/data/xml1/NCT0002xxxx/NCT00027222.xml`).